# Reducing queries on serialization with SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I currently have a serializer which uses two `SerializerMethodField` that access the same nested object, resulting in two db calls:

```
# models.py
class Onboarding(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_retailer_created = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# views.py
class StateView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerialiser

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

# serializers.py
class UserSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_onboarded = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_loyalty_onboarded = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('is_onboarded', 'is_loyalty_onboarded')

    def get_is_onboarded(self, obj):
        onboarding = obj.onboarding_set.first()
        if onboarding:
            return onboarding.is_retailer_created
        return False

    def get_is_loyalty_onboarded(self, obj):
        onboarding = obj.onboarding_set.first()
        if onboarding:
            return onboarding.is_complete
        return False
```

I'd like to roll this into one call if possible. Normally it would be possible to just use `prefetch_related`, but since the `get_object` is returning the specific user (and not a `queryset`) I don't think that solution works here.

Is there a way to prefetch the `Onboarding` model with the user? Or failing that have a single call to `Onboarding` instead of two?

Comment: The `.first()` looks rather *odd*. After all records are retrieved in a random order. So imagine that `is_retailer_created` is `True` for some and `False` for others. Then that means the result will be *random*.

Comment: Normally you can make use of `.annotate(..)` to perform aggregates/subqueries per group: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - this is intended behaviour - currently, there is only one onboarding model per user, so right now `.first()` is ok (despite it being bad code), it'll be updated later - and in terms of `annotate`, I don't see how that works in this instance, since there are no querysets to act on. I'd still be calling it twice for each `SerializerMethodField` wouldn't I?

Comment: then a `OneToOneField` should be used, since that is a `ForeignKey` with a uniqness constraint, and this thus means that there is one `Onboarding` per `User`. As for the `get_object`. The trick is to do the annotation in the `get_queryset`, since the `get_object` takes the queryset, and then obtains one record (for example where the pk matches). So even a `SingleObjectMixin` that offers the `get_object` method, will, in the background, use `get_queryset`.

Comment: can you share the view/viewset that you are using?

Comment: I'm aware of the correct way to do the relation - but there are additional constraints which require this setup. I've included the `view` in the question, it's a basic DRF retrieve view, the only overrides are the serializer and `get_object`, which returns the `request.user` which I wouldn't be able to get from a queryset (hence no `prefetch_related`).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was a little easier than anticipated. Just needed to save the `Onboarding` object in `__init__`.

```
# serializers.py
class UserSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_onboarded = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_loyalty_onboarded = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('is_onboarded', 'is_loyalty_onboarded')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserSerialiser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.onboarding = self.instance.onboarding_set.first()

    def get_is_onboarded(self, obj):
        if self.onboarding:
            return self.onboarding.is_retailer_created
        return False

    def get_is_loyalty_onboarded(self, obj):
        if self.onboarding:
            return self.onboarding.is_complete
        return False
```